# Migration and rollback

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem while working with `SQLite` database connection model in `laravel 4`.
After create schemas and run `migrate:install`, migrate, (db:seed) everything works perfectly. But if I delete the sqlite file for some reason, I am not able to recreate the file. migrate:install and migrate also run without any warnings but the app does not create the file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is not responsible for creating database files, they should exist when it tries to connect to them, but... PDO_SQLITE should create the database if it doesn't exists. Then, if it is not creating, you should check your folder permissions and webserver log files.